# How to center crop a video thumbnail (Square thumbnail) in ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg and I want to create a square thumbnail of size 500x500 by cropping the center of the video, irrespective of width and height. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want it to do if input width or height is smaller than 500?

Comment: It's just a preference. I think that the most minimum width of inputs would be 320 or more as I am targetting only mobile phones. The only thing that should be considered is that it should be a square and should be cropped from the center of the video. Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First crop, then scale.

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf "crop=w='min(min(iw\,ih)\,500)':h='min(min(iw\,ih)\,500)',scale=500:500,setsar=1" -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg
```

`x` and `y` for crop aren't set as they default to center crop.

---

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf "crop=w='min(iw\,ih)':h='min(iw\,ih)',scale=500:500,setsar=1" -vframes 1 thumbnail.jpg
```

This will select the largest square possible and scalethat to 500x500.

Comment: Thank you it's working fine but ffmpeg always shows the warning 'deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly' and 'Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss'. Is this something that I should be considered about?

Comment: Sorry but no change.

Comment: ```Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000001c4b31707c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c4b31707c0] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss```

Comment: Also I just have a request that, can you set the min width, height and scale according to input? The issue just came into my mind when @llogan mentioned it in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: It's fine to ignore it now, after you've added the format filter. @llogan's concern is accounted for, in my crop exprs.

Comment: But the thumbnail does not show the full part of the video's center (width). How can i solve this?

Comment: The full width won't be visible if width is greater than height, since you want to cut a square window.

Comment: No it's a 9:16 video.

Comment: What's the resolution?

Comment: The resolution is 776 x 1440

Comment: In this case, the middle 500x500 region will be cropped.

Comment: Is there any way to crop it to full width and scale the thumbnail to 500x500